# About Fermat's Integer Factoring algorithm

Tags: factorization

An implementation of [Fermat's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) that is a slight improvement on code in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RGUPQ6) book is here.

```
FermatFactor[n_?OddQ]:=Module[{s=Floor@Sqrt[n+0``1],r,u,v=1},
  If[s^2==n,Return@{s,s}];
  {r,u}={(s+1)^2-n,2*s+3};
  While[r!=0,
    While[r>0,
      r-=v;v+=2
    ];
    If[r<0,r+=u;u+=2]
  ];
  (u+{-v,v-2})/2
]
```

The main improvement above is the fast implementation of Floor[Sqrt[n]] from MichaelE2.
The above implementation will factor the following in less than 0.1 seconds!

```
SeedRandom[100];
p=10^50;
n=NextPrime@RandomInteger[{p-80000,p-60000}]*NextPrime@RandomInteger[{p+80000,p+60000}];
FermatFactor[n]
(*{99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999920467,100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000075667}*)
```

I have Mathematica Version 12.0.0 and FactorInteger[n] takes a very long time on that example.
Can FactorInteger in Mathematica 12.2 do it in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: No, it seems to take a very long time in 12.2.

Comment: No, `FactorInteger[n]` still takes a long time. But that example is chosen to play to the strengths of Fermat's algorithm. Replace one of the factors with `NextPrime@RandomInteger[{p/10 - 80000, p/10 - 60000}]` and `FermatFactor` takes a while.

Comment: I gave this some thought. Clearly, the integers that are hard to factor using FactorInteger, are rarely easy for Fermat's algorithm. Also the other algorithm(s) used by FactorInteger are much faster than Fermat's algorithm on average. Hence, Fermat's algorithm should not be used in FactorInteger.